# Face maps of cosimplicial abelian groups under Dold-Kan correspondence

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-stuff

This might be a stupid question, but I feel really confused how the cosimplicial Dold-Kan works explicitly...

### Recall

Let $$C_\bullet:=\dots\to C_2\to C_1\to C_0$$ be a chain complex of abelian groups in positive degrees.

By the Dold-Kan correspondence, there is an equivalence functor $\Gamma$, from the category of chain complexes to the category of simplicial abelian groups, which sends a simplicial object to the normalized chain complex.

The inverse functor $\Gamma^{-1}$ assignes the complex $C_\bullet$ a simplicial abelian group $$V\colon \Delta^{opp}\to \mathrm{Ab},$$ where $$V[n]=\oplus_{[n]\twoheadrightarrow[k]}C_k,$$ for any $f\colon [m]\to [n]$, the map $$V(f)\colon V[n]\to V[m]$$ is determined on each summand in the following way:

For the factor $C_k$ indexed by $a\colon [n]\twoheadrightarrow [k]$, the composition $$a\circ f\colon [m]\to[n]\twoheadrightarrow[k]$$ has an epi-monic factorization 
$$g\circ b\colon [m]\twoheadrightarrow[l]\hookrightarrow[k].$$
We take $C_k$ to $C_l$ indexed by $[m]\twoheadrightarrow[l]$. The map $C_k\to C_l$ is $$(-1)^k \mathrm{d}: C_k\to C_{k-1}\textrm{  when}\ l=k-1,$$ and zero otherwise, here $\mathrm{d}$ is the differential in $C_\bullet$，see (Simplicial Homotopy theory by Paul Goerss, P160)

I think there is a cosimpicial version of the Dold-Kan, but I can't figure out what are the cosimplicial face maps. Imitating the simplicial case, I think the setup should be the following:

### Setup

Let $$C^\bullet:=C^0\to C^1\to C^2\to \dots$$ be a cochain complex of abelian groups in positive degrees. We assign a cosimplicial abelian group $$W\colon \Delta\to\mathrm{Ab},$$ where $$W[n]=\oplus_{[k]\hookrightarrow[n]}C^k$$ for any $f\colon [m]\to [n]$, the map $W(f)\colon W[m]\to W[n]$ is determined on each summand in the following way:

For the factor $C^k$ indexed by $a\colon [k]\hookrightarrow[m]$, the composition $$f\circ a:[k]\hookrightarrow[m]\to [n]$$ has an epi-monic factorization
$$b\circ g:[k]\twoheadrightarrow[s]\hookrightarrow[n].$$

Naturally we may take the factor $C^k$ indexed by $a$ to the factor $C^s$ indexed by $b$.

### The problem is

The maps $C^k\to C^s$, (or $W[m]\to W[n]$) should involve the codifferentials $\delta\colon C^n\to C^{n+1}$ in $C^\bullet$, but since we have $[k]\twoheadrightarrow[s]$, if we define as in the simplicial case, we get zero face maps everywhere (because there is no surjection from $[k]$ to $[k+1]$)...

I am not sure how to fix this. And really hope there could be a textbook reference..

Comment: Recall that $\mathbf{c}\mathscr C = [\Delta,\mathscr C] = [\Delta^{\text{op}},\mathscr C^{\text{op}}]^{\text{op}} = (\mathbf{s}\mathscr C^{\text{op}})^{\text{op}}$. So when working with cosimplicial objects, you only have to 'reverse arrows twice': once in $\mathscr C$, and once again at the end. So you never actually reverse arrows in $\Delta$, and you don't replace surjections by injections.

Comment: The duality comes from the fact that 'abelian categories are self-dual' (the dual of an abelian category is an abelian category), not from some sort of self-duality of $\Delta$.

Comment: The cosimplicial Dold–Kan correspondence is simply the ordinary Dold–Kan correspondence applied to the opposite target category, which must be additive and idempotent complete.  Thus, your formula for W is not correct.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Explicitly, is it true that $W[n]$ be $\oplus_{[n]\twoheadrightarrow[k]}C^k$? In this case, for any $f\colon [n]\to [m]$, what should be the map $W(f)\colon W[n]\to W[m]$ restricted to the summand $C^k$ indexed by $[n]\twoheadrightarrow[k]$?